# I didn't find c3.css and c3.min.js for c3.js chart

Tags: c3.js

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="/path/to/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="/path/to/c3.min.js"></script>




</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ['data1', 230, 190, 300, 500, 300, 400]
        ]
    });
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ['data3', 130, 150, 200, 300, 200, 100]
        ]
    });
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data1'
    });
}, 2000);


</script>
```

I want to make c3.js chart any example. So i tried ... but i didn't find css and js for this...
Can anyone help me to find out c3.css  and c3.min.js path .... so i can solved this problem ...
Thank you every One.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start again using the [original zip file](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3), so I can be sure the files are in the right spot.

In the \htdocs\samples folder, open any sample.
It would say this in the head -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/c3.css">
```

Change it to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/c3.css">
```

Same for the line that calls the .js file.

Now, go back to the master folder, should be called c3-0.4.4 or something similar.
Copy all .css files and dump those in the css folder. Place all .js files in the js folder.